# Split string before each new letter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say that I have the following code:

```
var string = "A111B222C333D444E555";
var arr = string .match(/.{1,4}/g);
```

Which basically splits the string into an array every 4 characters and gives me the correct format:

```
0 => A111
1 => B222
3 => C333
4 => D444
5 => D555
```

The problem is that this code only works if every letter-number combination contains 4 characters. If the string is `A11B22C33D44E555`, the code would produce an incorrect format of

```
0 => A11B
1 => 22C3
3 => 3D44
4 => E555
```

when the desired output format is actually:

```
0 => A11
1 => B22
3 => C33
4 => D44
5 => E55
```

Is it possible to split the string before every new letter without worrying how many numbers there are after each letter?

Comment: How about `match(/([A-Z][0-9]+)/g)`. PS your example is wrong - the 5th result should be `E555`, not `D55` presumably. Or the input you provided is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the regular expression to match an alphabetical character, followed by one or more numbers:

```js
var string = "A11B22C33D44E555";
console.log(string.match(/[a-z]\d+/gi));
```

Comment: Works great, thanks for the help! I Will be able to accept the answer in 7 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

You can split the string by using a [lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead) to split when the next character is not a number:

```js
var string = "A11B22C33D44E555";

var result = string.split(/(?=\D)/);

console.log(result);
```